# buildSrc Version script object not being added root buildScript or any project context

Tags: gradle, kotlin, dependencies

i have a simple buildSrc configuration for dependency versions

a buildSrc/gradle.build.kts:

```
repositories {
    jcenter()
}

plugins {
    `kotlin-dsl`
}

dependencies {
    implementation(kotlin("script-runtime"))
}
```

I would like to point out that my kotlin script wouldnt work at all without the script-runtime dependency and I have never seen any documentation saying its required but once i added it an error went away:

"No script runtime was found in the classpath: class 'kotlin.script.templates.standard.ScriptTemplateWithArgs' not found. Please add kotlin-script-runtime.jar to the module dependencies."

Then i have a simple object script buildSrc/src/main/java/Versions.kts

```
object Versions {
    val kotlin = "1.3.61"
    val kotlinFrontentPlugin = "0.0.45"
}
```

Doesnt get much simpler.

Then in my root project i have:
build.gradle.kts:

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
        maven("https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/")
        maven("https://dl.bintray.com/kotlin/kotlin-eap")
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:${Versions.kotlin}")
        classpath("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-frontend-plugin:${Versions.kotlinFrontendPlugin}")
    }
}
```

This is all just straight up copy and paste. but all i can get is:

Line 12:         classpath("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:${Versions.kotlin}")
                                                                                   ^ Unresolved reference: kotlin

Line 13:         classpath("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-frontend-plugin:${Versions.kotlinFrontendPlugin}")
                                                                                     ^ Unresolved reference: kotlinFrontendPlugin

Does buildSrc just no longer work in builds anymore or is there yet some other undocumented setting or action i need to take?

Comment: using gradle 6.1.1

Comment: i also fixed the kotlinFrontentPlugin typo and it still doesnt work

Comment: Also found this in the build log: Task :buildSrc:jar
:jar: No valid plugin descriptors were found in META-INF/gradle-plugins

Answer (score 5):

Found the issue. I accidentally named my object as a script
Versions.kts when it needed to be Versions.kt